# $\mathbb{X}$ be a normal space, then $f^{-1}\left(U\right)$ is a normal subspace of $\mathbb{X}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{X}$ be a normal topological space, and $f:\mathbb{X}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous function.
Claim: if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ an open set, then $f^{-1}\left(U\right)$ is a normal subspace of $\mathbb{X}$.

Found this claim in some old lecture notes, and couldn't find a proof for it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true: since $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, $U$ in an $F_\sigma$ set in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., countable union of closed subsets). This holds in every metric space.
Hence $f^{-1}(U)$ is $F_\sigma$ in $X$, and $F_\sigma$ sets in normal spaces are normal (see, for instance, Engelking, General topology, 2.1.E).